# Microsoft Jet OLEDB 4.0 SQL Function Reference with ADO?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ado, jet

I'm using the the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider in Excel VBA ADO to connect to .csv and .xls files stored locally. I'm using the list of MS Access functions [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/index.php) as a guide for what I can write in SQL for Jet. But not all functions are supported and I'm having issues figuring out the syntax for certain things.

**Question 1**

Is there a reference somewhere for the set of SQL functions that I can use in my Jet queries through ADO?

**Question 2**

What's the right syntax for an IF (or CASE) statement? Without the IF, the query below runs fine.

```
    sql = "            SELECT "
    sql = sql & "        Date() as `Import Date`, "
    sql = sql & "        `Name` as `User`, "
    sql = sql & "        `Role Title` as `Role`, " 
    sql = sql & "        If 1=1 Then 1 Else 0 EndIf as `testing` "
    sql = sql & "      FROM [Sheet1$] a "
```

Resources

I don't see what I'm looking for in any of the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949429/where-can-i-find-the-documentation-for-the-particular-kind-of-sql-used-by-the-je), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317268/excel-sql-syntax-jet-oledb-reference) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733155/any-references-manuals-on-sql-in-excel-with-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-jet-4).

This looks like it should be the right place but it doesn't seem to show how to use IF/CASE in a SELECT statement, or what string functions are available

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/CH006252688.aspx

Comment: I am very surprised that works even without the If statement. You are using back-ticks and these are not used in Jet/ACE SQL and reserved words, which can cause problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For question 1, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733155/any-references-manuals-on-sql-in-excel-with-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-jet-4) lists some good resources, including a link to an [Intermediate SQL for Jet 4.0 article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx).

For question 2, do a search for the `Iif` and `Switch` functions.

Comment: Thanks Doug - the IIf worked beautifully. Now hopefully someone can unearth a general reference!